# Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, почему не работает flex-basis

Tags: html, css, веб-дизайн

на пороге весёлого нервного срыва, пока пытаюсь разобраться с flex-basis и flex.
Оно просто отказывается работать. Не было ещё ни одного раза, когда у меня сработал бы flex-basis с процентами (%), почти никогда не работает flex-basis с пикселями ))))) width и max-width -- как миленькие

```css
.flexbox-2 {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #1a62662f;
}

.flexbox-2-image {
    flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

```html
            <section class="flexbox-2"> <!-- container for flexbox-2-text and flexbox-2-image -->

                <div class="flexbox-2-image">
                    <img class="flexbox-2-image" src="./files/sad.png" alt="">
                </div>
                    
            </section> <!-- /.section-flexbox-2 -->
```

Comment: а почему вы решили, что у вас что-то не работает?

Comment: Потому что размеры никак не меняются

Comment: всё там меняется, у вас цвет фона для родительского контейнера задан, а у него ширина 100%. Задайте flexbox-2-image другой цвет и всё увидите. Либо в браузере по f12 посмотрите.